# Alternate way to send a ISO-8859-6 encoded requset to a server instead of Node.js, since Node.js does not support it

Tags: node.js, curl, requirejs, encode

I am trying to send a request with some ISO-8859-6 encoded data with [requestjs](https://github.com/request/request) which is not possible since Node does not support that encode.

I have done some other requests to that server before doing this one and update the Cookie everytime. I was trying to send that request via PHP or CURL but I could not do that.

Can I use PHP/CURL as a proxy only to redirect the request and meanwhile in PHP/CURL, before redirecting, I encode my data to ISO-8859-6?

What is your suggestion?

FYI: I cant change the server code!